# d3 Generate overlapping circles

Tags: d3.js, geometry

I'd like to generate a diagram like in the pic below. Everything (the circles) are static except for the point representing Q1, Q2, etc. This is my first time using D3 and have looked through Scott Murray's tutorials (http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/).

[question plotting http://dahlia.net78.net/evaluation.png](http://dahlia.net78.net/evaluation.png)

So far I've only managed to come up with the purple circles.

```
var dataset = [ 280, 230, 180, 130, 80, 30 ];

var w = 600;
var h = 600;

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", 300)
   .attr("cy", 300)
   .attr("r", function(d) { return d; })
   .attr("fill","mediumpurple")
   .attr("stroke","black")
   .attr("stroke-width",1);
```

I'm not sure how to continue and generate the overlapping circles. Anyone can point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groups for each group of circles. Please note that svg doesn't have layers, the circles are drawn in order.

```
var gPurple = svg.append('g');

gPurple.selectAll('circle')
    // your code here, you can also add the text

var gLeft = svg.append('g')
    // draw left circles here 

// add the white circle, above all the others
gPurple.append('circle')
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's what I've come up with. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVCmf/). Onto plotting the data :)

Comment: Excelent. I think that this tutorial http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/ can help you in the next steps (transitions?). Regards,

Comment: Would switch statements do it? I intend to get required data from database based on user ID. The chapter and level will determine in which circle do the questions belong to.

Comment: Maybe you can add a group for all the question circles and compute their position and radius based in the chapter and level.

Comment: Just to clarify, gLeft already have a group for question circles, correct? I can add things from there? And yes, I'll try coming up with the position and radius like you suggested.

Comment: Yes, gLeft is a group that can hold the circles.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30718/discussion-between-atikah-mohamad-and-pablo-navarro)