# How to add a set of fixed circles in D3 under updating .join-function ones

Tags: javascript, join, d3.js, visualization

I am very new to both D3 and JavaScript, so apologies in advance for possibly false terms and a confusing question. Have to try and get something together for my final assignment...

So I am illustrating a small dataset of land suitable for growing coffee, and how it's predicted to change by 2050 with three different scenarios.

I have updating circles that are joined with the data, but I would like to add fixed circles (with "none" fill and a stroke), that would be drawn with the first dataset and would remain there despite updates.

Many thanks in advance! Below is the code.

```js
var data = [
  [182.796,142.320,42.862,75.826],
  [131.2969,107.172,35.247,55.852],
  [116.3189,90.055,26.828,50.994],
  [104.1119,75.521,20.914,48.48]
]
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",1500)
  .attr("height",1000)

var marginLeft = 190
var circleOffset = 350
function draw(dataset){

  var serie = data.indexOf(dataset)
  canvas.selectAll("circle")

  .data(dataset)
  .join(
      function(enter){
          return enter.append("circle")
          .transition()
          .delay(300)
      },
      function(update){
          return update.attr("stroke","#00000000")
      },
      function(exit){
          return exit.transition()
          .duration(3000)
          .attr("r",0)
          .attr("cy",0)
          .remove()
      }
      )
  .attr("stroke-width","5")
  .attr("cy",200)
  .attr("fill",function(){
      if (serie === 0){
          return "green"
      } else if ( serie === 1){
          return "orange"
      } else if ( serie === 2){
          return "red"
      } else {
          return "darkred"
      }
  })
  .attr("opacity",0.5)
  .attr("cx",function(d,i){
      return i * circleOffset + marginLeft
  })
  .transition()
  .attr("r",10)
  .attr("r",function(d){
      return d
  })
}

// function draw2(dataset){
//     var serie = data.indexOf(dataset)
//     canvas.selectAll("circle")
//     .data(dataset)
//     .append("circle")
//         .attr("stroke","black")
//         .transition()
//         .delay(300)
//         .attr("stroke-width","5")
//         .attr("cy",200)
//         .attr("fill","none")
//         .attr("cx",function(d,i){
//         return i * circleOffset + marginLeft
//     })
//     .attr("r",10)
//     .attr("r",function(d){
//         return d
//     })

// }
var i = 0
d3.select("#buttons")
  .selectAll("button")
  .data(data)
  .join("button")
  .html(function(d,i){
      if (i === 0){
          return "2000"
      } else if ( i === 1){
          return "2050 (Scenario 1)"
      } else if ( i === 2) {
          return "2050 (Scenario 2)"
      } else if ( i === 3) {
          return "2050 (Scenario 3)"
      }})
  .on("click",function(e,d){
      // draw2(d)
      draw(d)


  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons"> </div>
```

I attempted to make another "draw" function that creates circles with no fill and a stroke, but it obviously started messing with the other draw function - probably since I'm selecting all circles in the canvas..? I also tried to append circles straight into a canvas but that again messes up the other content. Should I create classes or something..?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your intent - you want to have just a blank circle / ring around the rendered data, like [this](https://i.imgur.com/UOooiAZ.png), which would show up around the 2050 circles, regardless of the scenario / button?

Comment: If overlapping circles are what you're looking for, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772191) might help. Also, take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVCmf/) created by the question's OP.

Comment: Yes, overlapping circles, the circle showing despite the scenario (outlines from the first data point!! Sorry for being unclear. I'll check the links out, thank you!